# sparql how to group correctly this data

Tags: sparql

First of all, I didn't make a minimum example because i think that my problem can be understood without it.

Second, I didn't give you the data because i think that my problem can be solved without it. However, I'm open to give it to you if you ask.

This is my query:

```
select distinct (?x as ?likedItem) (?item as ?suggestedItem) ?similarity ?becauseOf  ((?similarity * ?importance * ?levelImportance) as ?finalSimilarity)

{
  values ?user {bo:ania}
  #the variable ?x is bound to the items the user :ania has liked.
  ?user rs:hasRated ?ratings.
  ?ratings a rs:Likes.
  ?ratings rs:aboutItem ?x.
  ?ratings rs:ratesBy   ?ratingValue.
  #level 0 class similarities
  {
    #extract all the items that are from the same class (type) as the liked items.
    #I assumed the being from the same class accounts for 50% of the similarities.
    #This value can be changed according to the test or the application domain.
    values ?classImportance {0.5} #class level
    bind (?classImportance as ?importance)
    bind( 4/7 as ?levelImportance)
  ?x  a ?class.
  ?class rdfs:subClassOf ?mainClass .
  ?mainClass rdfs:subClassOf rs:RecommendableClass .
  ?mainClass rs:hasSimilarityConfiguration ?similarityConfiguration .
  ?similarityConfiguration rs:hasClassSimilarity ?classSimilarity .
  ?classSimilarity rs:appliedOnClass ?class .
  ?classSimilarity rs:hasClassSimilarityValue ?similarity .
  ?item a ?class.
  bind (concat("it shares the same class, which is ", strafter(str(?class), "#"), ", with ", strafter(str(?x), "#")) as ?becauseOf)
  }
  union
   #level 0 instance similarities
  {
  #extract the items that share the same value for important predicates with the already liked items..
  #I assumed that having the same instance for important predicates account for 100% of the similarities.
  #This value can be changed according to the test or the application domain.
   values ?instanceImportance {1} #instance level
   bind (?instanceImportance as ?importance)
   bind( 4/7 as ?levelImportance)
   ?x  a ?class.
  ?class rdfs:subClassOf ?mainClass .
  ?mainClass rdfs:subClassOf rs:RecommendableClass .
  ?mainClass rs:hasSimilarityConfiguration ?similarityConfiguration .
  ?similarityConfiguration rs:hasPropertySimilarity ?propertySimilarity .
  ?propertySimilarity rs:appliedOnProperty ?property .
  ?propertySimilarity rs:hasPropertySimilarityValue ?similarity .
  ?x ?property ?value .
  ?item ?property ?value .
    bind (concat("it shares ", strafter(str(?value), "#"), " for predicate ", strafter(str(?property), "#"), " with ", strafter(str(?x), "#")) as ?becauseOf)
  }
  filter (?x != ?item)
}
```

This is the result:
[image]

As you see, the result contains **many values for the same suggestedItem**, I want to make group according to the suggestedItem and sum the values of `finalSimilarity`

I tried this:

```
select   ?item (SUM(?similarity * ?importance * ?levelImportance ) as ?finalSimilarity)  (group_concat(distinct ?x) as ?likedItem) (group_concat(?becauseOf ; separator = " ,and ") as ?reason) where
{
  values ?user {bo:ania}
  #the variable ?x is bound to the items the user :ania has liked.
  ?user rs:hasRated ?ratings.
  ?ratings a rs:Likes.
  ?ratings rs:aboutItem ?x.
  ?ratings rs:ratesBy   ?ratingValue.
  #level 0 class similarities
  {
    #extract all the items that are from the same class (type) as the liked items.
    #I assumed the being from the same class accounts for 50% of the similarities.
    #This value can be changed according to the test or the application domain.
    values ?classImportance {0.5} #class level
    bind (?classImportance as ?importance)
    bind( 4/7 as ?levelImportance)
  ?x  a ?class.
  ?class rdfs:subClassOf ?mainClass .
  ?mainClass rdfs:subClassOf rs:RecommendableClass .
  ?mainClass rs:hasSimilarityConfiguration ?similarityConfiguration .
  ?similarityConfiguration rs:hasClassSimilarity ?classSimilarity .
  ?classSimilarity rs:appliedOnClass ?class .
  ?classSimilarity rs:hasClassSimilarityValue ?similarity .
  ?item a ?class.
  bind (concat("it shares the same class, which is ", strafter(str(?class), "#"), ", with ", strafter(str(?x), "#")) as ?becauseOf)
  }
  union
   #level 0 instance similarities
  {
  #extract the items that share the same value for important predicates with the already liked items..
  #I assumed that having the same instance for important predicates account for 100% of the similarities.
  #This value can be changed according to the test or the application domain.
   values ?instanceImportance {1} #instance level
   bind (?instanceImportance as ?importance)
   bind( 4/7 as ?levelImportance)
   ?x  a ?class.
  ?class rdfs:subClassOf ?mainClass .
  ?mainClass rdfs:subClassOf rs:RecommendableClass .
  ?mainClass rs:hasSimilarityConfiguration ?similarityConfiguration .
  ?similarityConfiguration rs:hasPropertySimilarity ?propertySimilarity .
  ?propertySimilarity rs:appliedOnProperty ?property .
  ?propertySimilarity rs:hasPropertySimilarityValue ?similarity .
  ?x ?property ?value .
  ?item ?property ?value .
    bind (concat("it shares ", strafter(str(?value), "#"), " for predicate ", strafter(str(?property), "#"), " with ", strafter(str(?x), "#")) as ?becauseOf)
  }
  filter (?x != ?item)
}
group by ?item
order by desc(?finalSimilarity)
```

but the result is:

[image]

**this is something wrong in my way because** if you look at the finalSimilarity in, the value is `1.7`. However, if you sum that manually from the first query, you get `0.62` so I did something wrong,

could you help me discover it?

#### Please note that the two queries are the same, it is just the select statment are different

#### Hint

I am already able to solve it using two selects like this:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rs: <http://www.SemanticRecommender.com/rs#>
PREFIX bo: <http://www.BookOntology.com/bo#>
PREFIX :<http://www.SemanticBookOntology.com/sbo#>

select ?suggestedItem ( SUM (?finalSimilarity) as ?summedFinalSimilarity)  (group_concat(distinct strafter(str(?likedItem), "#")) as ?becauseYouHaveLikedThisItem) (group_concat(?becauseOf ; separator = " ,and ") as ?reason)
where {
select distinct (?x as ?likedItem) (?item as ?suggestedItem) ?similarity ?becauseOf  ((?similarity * ?importance * ?levelImportance) as ?finalSimilarity)
where
{
  values ?user {bo:ania}
  #the variable ?x is bound to the items the user :ania has liked.
  ?user rs:hasRated ?ratings.
  ?ratings a rs:Likes.
  ?ratings rs:aboutItem ?x.
  ?ratings rs:ratesBy   ?ratingValue.
  #level 0 class similarities
  {
    #extract all the items that are from the same class (type) as the liked items.
    #I assumed the being from the same class accounts for 50% of the similarities.
    #This value can be changed according to the test or the application domain.
    values ?classImportance {0.5} #class level
    bind (?classImportance as ?importance)
    bind( 4/7 as ?levelImportance)
  ?x  a ?class.
  ?class rdfs:subClassOf ?mainClass .
  ?mainClass rdfs:subClassOf rs:RecommendableClass .
  ?mainClass rs:hasSimilarityConfiguration ?similarityConfiguration .
  ?similarityConfiguration rs:hasClassSimilarity ?classSimilarity .
  ?classSimilarity rs:appliedOnClass ?class .
  ?classSimilarity rs:hasClassSimilarityValue ?similarity .
  ?item a ?class.
  bind (concat("it shares the same class, which is ", strafter(str(?class), "#"), ", with ", strafter(str(?x), "#")) as ?becauseOf)
  }
  union
   #level 0 instance similarities
  {
  #extract the items that share the same value for important predicates with the already liked items..
  #I assumed that having the same instance for important predicates account for 100% of the similarities.
  #This value can be changed according to the test or the application domain.
   values ?instanceImportance {1} #instance level
   bind (?instanceImportance as ?importance)
   bind( 4/7 as ?levelImportance)
   ?x  a ?class.
  ?class rdfs:subClassOf ?mainClass .
  ?mainClass rdfs:subClassOf rs:RecommendableClass .
  ?mainClass rs:hasSimilarityConfiguration ?similarityConfiguration .
  ?similarityConfiguration rs:hasPropertySimilarity ?propertySimilarity .
  ?propertySimilarity rs:appliedOnProperty ?property .
  ?propertySimilarity rs:hasPropertySimilarityValue ?similarity .
  ?x ?property ?value .
  ?item ?property ?value .
    bind (concat("it shares ", strafter(str(?value), "#"), " for predicate ", strafter(str(?property), "#"), " with ", strafter(str(?x), "#")) as ?becauseOf)
  }
  filter (?x != ?item)
}
}
group by ?suggestedItem
order by desc(?summedFinalSimilarity)
```

but to me that is a stupid solution and there must be a more clever one where i can take the aggregated data using one select

Comment: Your group concat makes a point to use distinct,  but your sum doesn't. Is it possible that you're including some addends more than once?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor the gropy concat is just, as you know, a text, so I don't want to repeat the same text many times that is why i used the distinct there. but in the finalSimilairty, it is not correct to put distinct, maybe some values, by accent, are the same, so i would be removing them.

Comment: Yes, but while you have duplicate strings, and you want to count each one just once,  are you ending up including the numerical bakers multiple times?  I'm not sure whether that's the issue here or not,  but it's something to consider

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Okay let's removed all that string thing, I just wanted to have aggregation on `suggestedItem` and the sum of `finalSimilarity`, I tried to remove the group_concat and I got the same results

Comment: Re: first sentence: Please provide a minimal example.  Longer is harder to understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without seeing your data, it's impossible to say, and with a query this big, it's probably not worth trying to debug the exact problem, but it's easy for this to happen if you can have duplicates (which would be easy to get, especially if you're using unions where some condition could match both parts).  For instance, suppose you have data like this:

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:>

:x :similar [ :sim 0.10 ; :mult 2 ] ,
            [ :sim 0.12 ; :mult 1 ] ,
            [ :sim 0.12 ; :mult 1 ] ,  # yup, a duplicate
            [ :sim 0.15 ; :mult 4 ] .
```

Then if you run this query, you'll get four result rows:

```
prefix : <urn:ex:>

select ?sim ((?sim * ?mult) as ?final) {
  :x :similar [ :sim ?sim ; :mult ?mult ] .
}
```

```
----------------
| sim  | final |
================
| 0.15 | 0.60  |
| 0.12 | 0.12  |
| 0.12 | 0.12  |
| 0.10 | 0.20  |
----------------
```

However, if you **select distinct**, you'll only see three:

```
select distinct ?sim ((?sim * ?mult) as ?final) {
  :x :similar [ :sim ?sim ; :mult ?mult ] .
}
```

```
----------------
| sim  | final |
================
| 0.15 | 0.60  |
| 0.12 | 0.12  |
| 0.10 | 0.20  |
----------------
```

Once you start to **group by** and **sum**, those non-distinct values will both get included:

```
select (sum(?sim * ?mult) as ?final) {
  :x :similar [ :sim ?sim ; :mult ?mult ] .
}
```

```
---------
| final |
=========
| 1.04  |
---------
```

That sum is the sum of all *four* terms, not the *three* distinct ones.  Even if the data doesn't have the duplicate values, the **union** can introduce the duplicate results:

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:>

:x :similar [ :sim 0.10 ; :mult 2 ] ,
            [ :sim 0.12 ; :mult 1 ] ,
            [ :sim 0.15 ; :mult 4 ] .
```

```
prefix : <urn:ex:>

select (sum(?sim * ?mult) as ?final) {
  { :x :similar [ :sim ?sim ; :mult ?mult ] }
  union
  { :x :similar [ :sim ?sim ; :mult ?mult ] }
}
```

```
---------
| final |
=========
| 1.84  |
---------
```

Since you found the need to use **group_concat(distinct …)**, I wouldn't be surprised if there are duplicates of that nature.

Comment: Nice example, and I'm pretty sure that the behavior shown here perfectly matches the problem of the question. Again, we all can see that it's worth to minimize the query and data for debugging...