# Sparql how to group this kind of data

Tags: sparql, rdf, aggregation, semantic-web, ontology

Because I was worried that you won't understand my situation, I made this visual illustration for you (click on the image to have a good quality version).

[image]

I know that a user (whoever is, we don't care), likes an item `(i1)`.

We want to suggest other items:

`i1` is similar to `i2` depending on a specific criteria (so there is a similarity value, let's call it `s1` )

`i1` is also similar to the same `i2`, but depending on another criteria( so there is a similarity value, let's call it `s2`)

`i1` is also similar to the same `i2`, but depending on a third criteria (so there is a similarity value, let's call it `s3`)

now `i2` belongs to two classes, and **each one of them affects the similarity by a specific weight**.

#### my problem

is i want to calculate the ultimate final similarity between `i1` and `i2` and i did almost all of it except the weight for the specific class.

my problem is that this weight should not be applied on the criteria that led to the selection of `i2`. in other words, if `i2` was select 1000 times using 1000 criteria, and `i2` belongs to a specific class, then the weight of that class will be applied just once, not 1000 times, and if `i2` belongs to two classes, the two weights for these two classes will be applied just once regarding of how many criterials led to select `i2`

#### Now

To make it easy for you to help me, i did this query (okay long but it has to be long to show you the case), but i also make it easy for you by making my query selects only the required infomration so you just can add another layer of select above it.

```
    prefix : <http://example.org/rs#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>


select  ?item ?similarityValue ?finalWeight where {
  values ?i1 {:i1}
  ?i1 ?similaryTo ?item .
  ?similaryTo :hasValue ?similarityValue .
  optional{
    ?item :hasContextValue ?weight .
  }
  bind (if(bound(?weight), ?weight, 1) as ?finalWeight)
}
```

So the result of that query is (look at the item `i2`) it repeats 6 times (as expected) with three different similarities (as expected because of three different criterias), and the `finalWeight`, which is the weight, repeats for each criteria:

[image]

#### Finally

Here is the data

```
@prefix : <http://example.org/rs#>
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

:i1 :similaryTo1 :i2 .
:similaryTo1 :hasValue 0.5 .
:i1 :similaryTo2 :i2 .
:similaryTo2 :hasValue 0.6 .
:i1 :similaryTo3 :i2 .
:similaryTo3 :hasValue 0.7 .
:i2 :hasContextValue 0.1 .
:i2 :hasContextValue 0.4 .
:i1 :similaryTo4 :i3 .
:similaryTo4 :hasValue 0.5 .
```

I hope you help me and I really appreciate it

#### So what I want to do

Imagine that there is no weight at all, so my query will be:

```
prefix : <http://example.org/rs#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
select  ?item ?similarityValue  where {
  values ?i1 {:i1}
  ?i1 ?similaryTo ?item .
  ?similaryTo :hasValue ?similarityValue .

}
```

and the result will be:
[image]

Then I make aggregation on the items with the sum of similarities like this:

```
prefix : <http://example.org/rs#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
select  ?item (SUM(?similarityValue) as ?sumSimilarities)  where {
  values ?i1 {:i1}
  ?i1 ?similaryTo ?item .
  ?similaryTo :hasValue ?similarityValue .
}
group by ?item
```

and the result is:
[image]

What I want is to multiply each row of this result by the sum of **two weights** that are associated with `?item`, which are (0.1 * 0.4) for i2 and (1) for i3

Notice that some items doesn't have two weights, some has one, some nothing, and notice that even for those that have two, the two values could be the same so be careful if you use distinct here.

Lastly, I'm saying always **two** just as an example, but in the real life, this number comes from the dynamic system.

<3>Update 
After `@Joshua Taylor` answer, I understood his sample data as:

[image]

Comment: This query is so long that it's quite hard to analyze it. Just as a comment and probably off-topic: You could make it a little more compact if you replace paths of triple patterns in which you do not need the intermediate nodes by using property paths, e.g. instead of having `?s :p1 ?o1 . ?o1 :p2 ?o2 .` you can write `?s :p1/:p2 ?o` - of course only if your triple store supports SPARQL 1.1

Comment: @AKSW I will try to exaplain the query for you, as I said in the question, there are man criteria to select the similar items to an entered item. the first 4 blocks of the query are just to work with these critera, so basically you left just one block that ads this weight (userContextFinalValue). Kindly if you need more description i can tell you, i did minimize the code to the least possile senario in which I can show you the situation.

Comment: @AniaDavid But you **don't** need data or a query this complex in order to reproduce the issues.  Didn't the sample data I created in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36362790/1281433) to your earlier question, [sparql how to group correctly this data](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36357083/1281433) explain the problem there?  Isn't this pretty much the same situation?

Comment: I think in the section of this question, **my problem**, I think you've actually come very close to describing what you're *trying* to do, and I think if you just sit down and figure out the actual mathematical formula that you're trying to implement, then the *query* will become much simpler.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor for the question you've mentioned, it comes *after* calculating the similarity, and that's why I asked this question to calcuate the simialrity then i would go back to your quesiton. anyway, the example there inspires me to do a minimal exampel for this qestion. though it won't be the same, but i will try, and update you both once finish

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I update the question with *minimual* data this time

Comment: @AKSW I update the question with *minimual* data this time

Comment: Can you please define what the actual computation is supposed to be?  You end up with a list of (similarItem, value, weight) tuples, where you can have multiple tuples with the same similarItem (but with different values and weights).  What do you actually want as the final value?

Comment: It sounds like maybe you want something like `sumOver(property, propertyWeight * sumOver(similarItem, similarItemSimilarity))`.  I think that once you specify the formula, the SPARQL query will come right out from it.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I updated my question to show you what I want to do, could you have a look please ?

Comment: @AniaDavid Thank you, I think that the update will help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Some data

First, some data that we can work with.  The item **:a** has a bunch of similarity connections, each of which specifies an item and a reason.  **:a** can be similar to an item for a few different reasons, and there can even be duplicated similarities with the same item and reason.  I think that this matches your use case so far. (Sample data in the question could make this clearer, but I think this is along the lines of what you've got).  Then, each item has contextual value, and each reason has an optional weight.

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:>

:a :similarTo [ :item :b ; :reason :p ] ,
              [ :item :b ; :reason :p ] , # a duplicate
              [ :item :b ; :reason :q ] ,
              [ :item :b ; :reason :r ] ,
              [ :item :c ; :reason :p ] ,
              [ :item :c ; :reason :q ] ,
              [ :item :d ; :reason :r ] ,
              [ :item :d ; :reason :s ] .

:b :context 0.01 .
:b :context 0.02 .
:c :context 0.04 .
:d :context 0.05 .
:e :context 0.06 . # not used

:p :weight 0.1 .
:q :weight 0.3 .
:r :weight 0.5 .
# no weight for :s
:t :weight 0.9 . # not used
```

It sounds like what you want to do is to compute the sum the context values for the similar items, including the context value for each occurrence, but to sum the reason weights, but only for the distinct occurrences.  If that's the correct understanding, then I think you want something like the following.

### Getting weights for the reasons

The first step is to be able to get the sum of weights for the distinct reasons for each similar item.

```sql
prefix : <urn:ex:>

select * where {
  values ?i { :a }

  #-- get the sum of weights of distinct reasons
  #-- for each item that is similar to ?i.
  { select ?item (sum(?weight) as ?propertyWeight) {
      #-- get the distinct properties for each ?item
      #-- along with their weights.
      { select distinct ?item ?property ?weight {
          ?i :similarTo [ :item ?item ; :reason ?property ] .
          optional { ?property :weight ?weight_ }
          bind(if(bound(?weight_), ?weight_, 0.0) as ?weight)
        } }
    }
    group by ?item
  }
}
```

```
------------------------------
| i  | item | propertyWeight |
==============================
| :a | :b   | 0.9            |
| :a | :c   | 0.4            |
| :a | :d   | 0.5            |
------------------------------
```

### Getting weights for the items

Now, you still need the sum of the values for each item, counting the weight for each occurrence.  So we extend the query:

```sql
select * where {
  values ?i { :a }

  #-- get the sum of weights of distinct reasons
  #-- for each item that is similar to ?i.
  { select ?item (sum(?weight) as ?propertyWeight) {
      #-- get the distinct properties for each ?item
      #-- along with their weights.
      { select distinct ?item ?property ?weight {
          ?i :similarTo [ :item ?item ; :reason ?property ] .
          optional { ?property :weight ?weight_ }
          bind(if(bound(?weight_), ?weight_, 0.0) as ?weight)
        } }
    }
    group by ?item
  }

  #-- get the sum of the context values
  #-- for each item.
  { select ?item (sum(?context_) as ?context) {
      ?item :context ?context_ .
    }
    group by ?item
  }
}
```

```
----------------------------------------
| i  | item | propertyWeight | context |
========================================
| :a | :b   | 0.9            | 0.03    |
| :a | :c   | 0.4            | 0.04    |
| :a | :d   | 0.5            | 0.05    |
----------------------------------------
```

Note that it's OK that search for **?item :context ?context_ .** in the second subquery, and don't even ensure that **?item** is one of the similar items.  Since the results of the two subqueries are joined, we'll only get results for the values of **?item** that were also returned by the first subquery.

### Putting them together

Now you can just add, or multiply, or do whatever else you want to do to combine the sum of the reason weights with the sum of the context values.  For instance, if you're summing them:

```sql
select ?i ?item ((?propertyWeight + ?context) as ?similarity) where {
  values ?i { :a }

  #-- get the sum of weights of distinct reasons
  #-- for each item that is similar to ?i.
  { select ?item (sum(?weight) as ?propertyWeight) {
      #-- get the distinct properties for each ?item
      #-- along with their weights.
      { select distinct ?item ?property ?weight {
          ?i :similarTo [ :item ?item ; :reason ?property ] .
          optional { ?property :weight ?weight_ }
          bind(if(bound(?weight_), ?weight_, 0.0) as ?weight)
        } }
    }
    group by ?item
  }

  #-- get the sum of the context values
  #-- for each item.
  { select ?item (sum(?context_) as ?context) {
      ?item :context ?context_ .
    }
    group by ?item
  }
}
```

```
--------------------------
| i  | item | similarity |
==========================
| :a | :b   | 0.93       |
| :a | :c   | 0.44       |
| :a | :d   | 0.55       |
--------------------------
```

### Final cleanup

Looking at the final query, two things bugged me a bit.  The first is that we retrieved the reason weight for each solution in the inner subquery, whereas we only need to retrieve it once per property per item.  That is, we can move the **optional** part to the outer, inner subquery.  Then, we've got a **bind** that sets a variable that we only use in the aggregation.  We can replace it by summing **[coalesce](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-coalesce)(?weight,0.0)** to use **?weight** if it's bound, and **0.0** otherwise.  After making those changes, we end up with:

```sql
select ?i ?item ((?propertyWeight + ?context) as ?similarity) where {
  values ?i { :a }

  #-- get the sum of weights of distinct properties
  #-- using 0.0 as the weight for a property that doesn't
  #-- actually specify a weight.
  { select ?item (sum(coalesce(?weight,0.0)) as ?propertyWeight) {

      #-- get the distinct properties for each ?item.
      { select distinct ?item ?property {
          ?i :similarTo [ :item ?item ; :reason ?property ] .
        } }

       #-- then get each property's optional weight.
       optional { ?property :weight ?weight }
    }
    group by ?item
  }

  #-- get the sum of the context values
  #-- for each item.
  { select ?item (sum(?context_) as ?context) {
      ?item :context ?context_ .
    }
    group by ?item
  }
}
```

It's not a huge change, but it makes things a little bit cleaner, I think, and a little bit easier to understand.

### Comments

It's almost become my mantra at this point, but these kinds of questions are much easier to answer if there's sample data provided.  In this case, most of the actual mechanics of *how* you're getting these values in the first place doesn't really matter.  It's how you're aggregating them afterward that does.  That's why we can use really simple data like what I created from scratch at the beginning of this answer.

I think that the big take-away from this, though, is that one of the important techniques in using SPARQL (and other query languages, too, I expect) is having separate subqueries and joining their results.  In this case, we ended up with a couple of subqueries, because we really needed to group in a couple of different ways.  This could have have been simpler if SPARQL provided a **distinct by** operator, so that we could say something like

```
sum(distinct by(?property) ?weight)
```

but that has the issue that if a distinct property could have more than one weight, which of those weights would you choose?  So the solution really seems to be a couple of subqueries so that we can do a few different kinds of grouping.  This is why I was asking about the actual formula you're trying to compute.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the appreciated efforts, first of all, i must say that I did something wrong by saying *What I want is to multiply each row of this result by the sum of two weights that are associated with ?item, which are (0.1 *+* 0.4) for i2 and (1) for i3* where I should have said *multiply* instead of *sum*, but I think that won't change a lot. Secondly you understood me but in the inverse way. I will show you in the next comment

Comment: Kindly check the updated image, you said *It sounds like what you want to do is to compute the sum the context values for the similar items, including the context value for each occurrence, but to sum the reason weights, but only for the distinct occurrences* , but actually, what I want is: *compute the sum the reasons values (all of them) and multiply it with the (multiply context for each item). if you look at the image i put, then i want `(:r weight + :p weight + :q weight) * (:b context * :b context)` = `(0.5 + 0.1 + 0.3)* (0.01 * 0.02)`

Comment: but please don't change (update) the answer, i am still reading it,

Comment: @Ania if I understand you,  it just means you'd replace the + in my answer with a *.

Comment: and the default value from 0 to 1, i guess, but i am still reading it

Comment: I will assume that your answer contains many sections, each one starts by the bold sentence, just to make it easy to refer to what I want, so you answer contains, the following sections: `Some data`, `Some data`, `Getting weights for the reasons`, `Putting them together`, `Final cleanup`

Comment: In the third second, which is `Getting weights for the items`, the following query: `#-- get the sum of the context values
  #-- for each item.
  { select ?item (sum(?context_) as ?context) {
      ?item :context ?context_ .
    }
    group by ?item
  }`  calculates the sum of the context for each item. while, **and i am sorry again it is my mistake** I need the multip of the context for each item. is it possible just to update this part please?

Comment: What do you mean by the "the multip of the context for each item."?  Do you mean the product of the distinct context values?

Comment: @AniaDavid If that's what you're looking for, you'll be a little bit disappointed, since according to [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#aggregates), "Aggregates defined in version 1.1 of SPARQL are COUNT, SUM, MIN, MAX, AVG, GROUP_CONCAT, and SAMPLE.".  There's no **product** aggregate in the standard.  An endpoint might support one (I don't know if Jena has it or not), and endpoints may allow you to define custom ones (Jena does).  You could also do some kind of hack like `select (sum(log(?context)) as ?logSum) (exp(?logSum) as ?product)` if the math functions are defined.

Comment: now I reached the `final clean up` section, all clear really, I appreciated it. For the **product of distinct values** that is an important for me because in some cases, the business owner could but a value (zero) so this item should never ever be choosen, it is like you are a male, and i don't want to suggest you a female close. I am thinking to take the results that you've got at the end of `Getting weights for the items` and send the results to my application layer but do the multiply there. (continute next comment)

Comment: Kindly I would like to take your opinion, Note, that if you have a math equation that produce a very low number, it is okay by me. I mean like instead of putting zero for the items that we dont want to select, we may put a very low values (like 0.001), and then if there is a math function that we can apply that if it founds a small values, it gives me a really small value in which the other items (that have a bigger weight value) will have a higher values. (am i making sense to you? )

Comment: @AniaDavid There's a MIN aggregate function, and you could certainly just find the minimum value and check whether it's less than some threshold, and if it is, then exclude the result somehow.

Comment: Or tell them that if they don't want to recommend an item, don't put the value as zero, but put it as (0.092) (for instance) and in my sparql, i do a filter on that value, will that work in your opinino please? (I am understood the first 4 sections of your answer, and I am trying to apply them on my dataset)

Comment: @AniaDavid In my opinion, I'd prefer to keep the similarity values pure, and not use special values to indicate other conditions.  That is, rather than using some special value (like 0.092, or whatever), I'd just add an additional property and check for that.  If you use some special value, then you always run the risk of forgetting to check for it, or that you need it as a value, but it has the unintended effect.

Comment: Okay I got your idea, I am still trying to work on it according to your answer, but now I am sorry I have to go early because I have already plans, I will continue tomorrow and i will update you. i have no words to say thank you for you,

Comment: Hello, I have a problem in the second query block in your `Getting weights for the items` section. I got the idea, and I know how to do with *your* graph, but I'm having problems to do it in my graph. I'd like to ask you about how can I ask this question. Should I ask a new question? (kindly note that I have a specific problem related to my dataset so I will be giving you my query). what do you think please ? Appreciate it

Comment: Hello, I did the fourth section, no need for a new question,  now I'm continuing, I'm sorry for late, my graph is really big

Comment: Appreciate it very much, I highly value the efforts, it is done now B-)